# Android: If I send an SMS using SmsManager, does it automatically resend failed sms?

Tags: android, sms, smsmanager, android-sms

If I'm sending an SMS from my app using SmsManager and the SMS fails to send, does the SmsManager automatically retry sending SMS for me - or do I have to manage this myself in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no it does not.

if there is no signal to send  a message and it fails.. the phone SHOULD automatically continue to try resending..

currently it simply reports that it has failed and puts it in a list of failed 
messages.

so, no...You can catch if the message was sent or not and repsond to these events.

[Refer here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html)

Comment: Link is broken.